# Manipulating Thai Characters in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, multibyte, thai, southeast-asian-languages

I'm struggling getting Thai characters and PHP working together. This is what I'd like to do:

```
<?php
   mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
   $string = "ทาง";
   echo $string[0];
?>
```

But instead of giving me the first character of $string (ท), I just get some messed up output. However, displaying $string itself works fine.

File itself is of course UTF-8 as well. Content-Type in Header is also set to UTF-8. I changed the neccessary lines in php.ini according to [this site](http://chinesenotes.com/chinese_text_manipulating.php).

utf8_encoding() and utf8_decoding() also don't help. Maybe any of you has an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP When you access a string with `$string[0]` it doesn't return the fist character, but the first byte.

You should use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) instead. For example:

```
mb_substr($string, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
```

**Note**: Since you are using `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` you may as well ignore the last parameter.

---

This happens because PHP is not aware of the encoding a string is in (that is: the encoding is **not** stored in the string object). So it will treat it as ANSI/ASCII by default. If you don't want that, then you must use the [Multibyte String Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) (mb_*).

When you set `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');` you are telling it to use `UTF-8` for all the Multibyte String Function, but not for anything else.